# Provide different ClientInterceptor per request using Spring Web Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I've created a custom web service client by extending `WebServiceGatewaySupport` and also implement custom `ClientInterceptor` to log some request/response data.
I have to create new interceptor for every call because it has to store some data about the request.

The problem occurs when I make two or more calls to my client. The first request applies its own interceptor with its `clientId`. The second should do the same. But since both requests use the same `WebServicetemplate` in my client, the second request replaces the interceptor with its own, with its `clientId` there.

As a result, I should get the following output to the console:

```
Request: clientId-1
Request: clientId-2
Response: clientId-1
Response: clientId-2
```

But I got this:

```
Request: clientId-1
Request: clientId-2
Response: clientId-2
Response: clientId-2
```

Here is come code examples (just for understanding how it should work):

```java
@Data
class Response {
    private final String result;

    public Response(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

@Data
class Request {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
}

@Data
class Context {
    private final String clientId;
}

@Data
class Client {
    private final String clientId;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
}

class CustomInterceptor extends ClientInterceptorAdapter {
    private final String clientId;

    public CustomInterceptor(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        System.out.println("Request: " + clientId);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        System.out.println("Response: " + clientId);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        System.out.println("Error: " + clientId);
        return true;
    }
}

@Component
class CustomClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Response sendRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        CustomInterceptor[] interceptors = {new CustomInterceptor(context.getClientId())};
        setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return (Response) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class CustomService {

    private final CustomClient customClient;

    public String call(Request request, Context context) {
        Response response = customClient.sendRequest(request, context);
        return response.getResult();
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class CustomController {

    private final CustomService service;

    public CustomController(CustomService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String test(@RequestBody Client client) {
        Request request = new Request(client.getFirstName(), client.getLastName());
        Context context = new Context(client.getClientId());
        return service.call(request, context);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement custom interceptors with some state for each call? Preferably without any locks on `WebServicetemplate` to avoid performance degradation.

Comment: Did you add this interceptor in interceptor registry?

Comment: No, I haven't. Current implementation works fine until I send two or more requests in the same time.

Comment: `ClientInterceptorAdapter` it's a default implementation of `ClientInterceptor`. I use this just to not holding empty method `afterCompletion` in my `CustomInterceptor`

Comment: What are imports for context and request in CustomClient?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated sample of code to show that I'm saving to interceptor data not from the object that sending via `WebServiceTemplate` but from another object named `context`. So the data that needs to be processed in the interceptor doesn't went into the `WebServiceTemplate` and I can't get it from the `MessageContext`.

Comment: what is import for `Context` in `CustomClient.java`?

Comment: It's a custom class that holds some metadata about processing current request (`clientId`, `traceId` etc)

Comment: How CustomClient is being called? Any sample code? I am trying to generate issue in my code that you are facing,

Comment: Simply `customClient.sendRequest(request, context);`

Comment: how do you construct request and context, provide sample.Edit it in your question.

Comment: Okay. I've added some more examples of code. This is just a dummy model of my real project

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I've found the solution for my case.
I've created an implementation of `WebServiceMessageCallback` and using it I'm saving data of each request not in interceptor but in `WebServiceMessage`'s mime header.

```java
@Data
class CustomMessageCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback {

    private final String clientId;
    
    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        MimeHeaders headers = ((SaajSoapMessage) message).getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("X-Client-Id", clientId);
    }
}
```

And pass this callback in my client implementation:

```java
@Component
class CustomClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Response sendRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        CustomInterceptor[] interceptors = {new CustomInterceptor()};
        setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return (Response) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new CustomMessageCallback(context.getClientId()));
    }
}
```

So now I can get this data while processing request/response/error via interceptor.

```java
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    String clientId = ((SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest())
        .getSaajMessage()
        .getMimeHeaders()
        .getHeader("X-Client-Id")[0];
    System.out.println("Request: " + clientId);
    return true;
}
```